# CSS transition in Firefox

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm using this for my link-hover-transition-effect:

```
-webkit-transition: color 250ms ease-in 0;
-moz-transition: color 250ms ease-in 0;
-o-transition: color 250ms ease-in 0;
transition: color 250ms ease-in 0;
```

It works in Opera, Chrome but not in Firefox. I don't care about IE.

According to this, it should work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions#AutoCompatibilityTable

Any idea what is wrong with that?

Comment: Can you try changing `250ms` to `0.25s`?

Comment: same effect... chrome, opera ok ... firefox dont want to

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle.com example? I'd like to see this in action.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dennym/An4zV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`-moz-transition: color 0.25s ease-in 0s;`

Comment: had to add the unit of zero -.- cost me 2 hours of searching thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `0` at the end was breaking the transformation.

This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/An4zV/2/

Comment: se answer before yours... you have to add the unit to the zero